# Presenting Three Monitors as One Resolution on Late 2013 Mac Pro

Tags: gaming, amd-graphics-card, mac-pro

I'm trying to play Euro Truck Simulator 2 on a Late 2013 Mac Pro with an AMD FirePro D300 2048 MB graphics card. I have three monitors connected - an Apple Cinema Display in the center, and two Dell P2210s on either side. ETS's [documentation](http://www.eurotrucksimulator2.com/multimon_config.php) states that

> "Only multimon configurations which are presented to the game as a
>   single big resolution virtual screen are supported. You need to be
>   using either Nvidia Surround or AMD Eyefinity or equivalent depending
>   on your graphics chipset type."

I can't find any sort of graphics control panel that would allow me to enable this option. I can play the game on the center monitor, but I'd like it to run on all three. Is running the game on all three monitors with this setup a possibility? What do I need to change to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a caveat, I do not believe your graphics card will yield playable results on 3 displays of your resolution.

However, the information you are looking for is that Eyefinity only works on Windows and you will need to download the Radeon driver configuration program (Called Radeon Software Crimson Edition as of this answer). In there there should be an Eyefinity section that should guide you through the setup of an Eyefinity display

Comment: So there's no option for multi monitor support in OS X?

Comment: there is a difference between having multiple monitors on the same computer which are each presented as a separate display, which you are using currently, and requires no special software, and a multi monitor display, which uses software to pretend to be a single display spanning multiple monitors. The software for the latter exists for windows and (occasionally) linux, due to market and GPU power (macs don't tend to have GPUs capable of multi-monitor gaming).